# BibTex generates an empty .bbl file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am new to Latex and I have a problem with generating bibliography.

I created a file `ArticleEGC.bib` and I am calling it from my `ArticleEGC.tex` file but when I generate the final `pdf`, it doesn't get the references and the citations are not called. The generated `bbl` file also turns out to be empty.

This is the `bib` file :

```
@PHDTHESIS{anass:2011,
    Author         = {El Haddadi, A.},
    School         = {Université Toulouse III Paul Sabatier},
    Title          = {Fouille multidimensionnelle sur les données textuelles visant à extraire les réseaux sociaux et sémantiques pour leur exploitation via la téléphonie mobile},
    Type           = {Thèse de doctorat},
    Year           = 2011
}

@PHDTHESIS{ilheme:2009,
    Author         = {Ghalamallah, I.},
    School         = {Université Toulouse III Paul Sabatier},
    Title          = {\'Proposition d'un modèle d'analyse exploratoire multidimensionnelle dans un contexte d'Intelligence Economique},
    Type           = {Thèse de doctorat},
    Year           = {2009}
}

@TECHREPORT{rees:2010,
    Author         = {Rees, K.},
    Institution    = {Periscopic},
    Note           = {Review on Gephi},
    Title          = {Data Visualization Review: Gephi, Free Graph Exploration Software},
    Year           = {2010}
}

@ARTICLE{bernard:2009,
    Author         = {Dousset, B.},
    Journal        = {SciWatch Journal},
    Title          = {Intelligence économique : proposition d’un outil dédié à l’analyse relationnelle},
    Volume         = {3},
    Year           = {2008}
}
```

This is the generated `bbl` file :

```
\providecommand\Fr{}
\providecommand\Eng{}
\providecommand\andname{and}
\providecommand\andnamec{and}

\begin{thebibliography}{}


\end{thebibliography}
```

This is the call from the `tex` file :

```
Les points forts et faibles de Gephi cités ci-après sont basés sur une étude de \citet{rees:2010} ainsi que sur notre propre étude.

\bibliographystyle{rnti}
\bibliography{ArticleEGC}

\end{document}
```

The generated pdf gives this :

```
Les points forts et faibles de Gephi cités ci-après sont basés sur une étude de ? ainsi que sur notre propre étude.
```

The log shows the following messages :

```
[BibTeX] finished with exit code 2
```

and :

```
Citation `rees:2010` on page 3 undefined on line173.
```

and :

```
./articleegc.bbl:9: Empty `thebibliography` environment on input line9.
./articleegc.tex:0: There were undefined citations.
```

I am using Kile 2.1.3 under Ubuntu 14.04.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: do you `\cite` the documents in your document? (and did you run latex before running bibtex) bibtex extracts the documents that you cite, it doesn't by default list the whole bib file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! Please check the update!

Comment: bibtex got an error, there should be a blg file with its log...

Comment: i'm not familiar with the `rnti` bibliographystyle, and it's not on ctan.  so i can't check to see whether it recognizes `\citet`.  on the assumption that it does not, you should be able to force a particular item to be placed in a `.bbl` file by including a line `\nocite{rees:2010}` in your file.

Comment: The first reference in your .bib file is missing the brackets from around the year.

Comment: Try using binbtex. for example:
bibtex filename.aux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have checked the `blg` file.

I have changed the file names to be fully in small letters instead of capital and small letters `articleegc.tex` and `articleegc.bib` instead of `ArticleEGC.tex` and `ArticleEGC.bib` and it worked!

Is that even logical?

Comment: the filename in the  `\bibligraphy` command has to match the filename of the `.bib` file. You can use uppercase letters but they have to match.